# How to remove few columns from every row of a dataset in python?

Tags: list, python-3.6

Process a file (which has 18-20 columns of data) in a short time by removing a few columns of junk data initially.

We are receiving a file from which have data as shown below:

```
'apple', 'guava', 'papaya', 'grapes', 'kashmir', '', 'xadjkladihad'
'apple', 'guava-red', 'papaya', 'grapes', 'himachal', '',  'dsdhks'
.....
.....
```

And most of the junked data which we do not need also is now being processed from which we want to remove a few columns so that processing of file containing data finishes in a short time.

```
desired = [fruit for fruit in fruits if len(fruit) > 1]
```

The present code is processing all the junk data many times for places, types, etc. What I want is, process all data by removing junk initially.

Comment: What is "junk" in your application?

Comment: junk data coming in the file. That's normal for us. We've to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Well! if you carefully observe the above code and the requirement, the job will become little easier and simple.

Let's suppose that we have thousands of rows and 15 columns and we want to remove a few columns from the end.

```
desired_fruits = [fruit[0:12] for fruit in fruits[:] if len(fruit) > 1]
```

Here we are slicing the last 2 columns i.e., 14 and 15th and fruits[:] is the only copy of fruits list.

Here you can play with the figures of the columns, where 0 is the first column and 12 is the thirteenth column.

Comment: This will surely resolve my issue, Need to slice a few columns of junk data from processing.